# Print atleast once with empty fields..?

Tags: visualforce

I have a code that will prints in PDF when at least one record is inserted. If no record is inserted the details will not be printed even note field also. if i fill note field, i want the printout of all fields with empty. I am attached image see this you will get an idea.

the code is

```
<tr>
        <td><table width="700" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  >
            <apex:repeat value="{!bdsrecords6}" var="rec">
              <tr>
                <td><table width="700" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-left:#000 solid 1px;">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="113"  align="center" style="{!rec.Width_Module_m__c}"><strong>
                        <apex:outputText style="font-size:10px;" value="Wall Trims Color" rendered="{!rec.Version_Created__c}"/>
                        </strong></td>
                      <td width="121"  align="center" style="{!rec.Width_Module_m__c}"><strong>
                        <apex:outputText value="Item No" rendered="{!rec.Version_Created__c}"/>
                        </strong></td>
                      <td width="94" align="left" style="{!rec.Width_Module_m__c}"><strong>
                        <apex:outputText value="Description" rendered="{!rec.Version_Created__c}"/>
                        </strong></td>
                      <td width="94"  style="{!rec.Width_Module_m__c}"><strong>
                        <apex:outputText value="BMT" rendered="{!rec.Version_Created__c}"/>
                        </strong></td>
                      <td width="126" style="{!rec.Width_Module_m__c}"><strong>
                        <apex:outputText value="Finish" rendered="{!rec.Version_Created__c}"/>
                        </strong></td>
                      <td width="121"  align="center" style="{!rec.Width_Module_m__c}"><strong>
                        <apex:outputText value="Color" rendered="{!rec.Version_Created__c}"/>
                        </strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="113" ></td>
                      <td width="121" ><apex:outputText value="{!rec.Item__c}" rendered="{!rec.ParentPIFBDS__c == pageobj.Id}"/></td>
                      <td width="94" ><apex:outputText value="{!rec.Description__c}" rendered="{!rec.ParentPIFBDS__c == pageobj.Id}"/></td>
                      <td width="94" ><apex:outputText value="{!rec.BMT1__c}" rendered="{!rec.ParentPIFBDS__c == pageobj.Id}"/></td>
                      <td width="126" ><apex:outputText value="{!rec.Finish12__c}" rendered="{!rec.ParentPIFBDS__c == pageobj.Id}"/></td>
                      <td width="121" ><apex:outputText value="{!rec.Color15__c}" rendered="{!rec.ParentPIFBDS__c == pageobj.Id}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><apex:outputPanel >
                    <table width="700" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
                      <tr style="{!rec.Width_M7__c}">
                        <td align="center" width="113" ></td>
                        <td align="left" width="576" valign="middle" ><strong>Note :</strong>
                          <apex:outputText value="{!pageobj.Note35__c}"/></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </apex:outputPanel></td>
              </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
    </table></td>
</tr>
```

[image: printout]

[image: pdf printout]

[image: Filling Form]

[image: Required Print]

Comment: Vijay - welcome to SFSE. Thanks for posting the screen shot -- what exactly is not working? - please be specific by identifying the code lines/elements. It might also be helpful to reduce the problem space by removing unnecessary lines of VF

Comment: if you didn't add any Items in Item No. like 123.0. Comments in Note field will not printed in pdf. My actual requirement is, if i fill Note Field and not added any items. In this case also i want the printout with empty fields. i add more screenshot to get idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell, but I think the trouble is you have the Notes sections within the `apex:repeat` element.  If there are no items to repeat across, then no notes will be displayed.

If I understand the behaviour you're after, you'll need to move the Notes section outside the `apex:repeat`.

Comment: if i move the Note section from outside the apex:repeat then note will printed but empty fields of Item No, Description, BMT, Finish, Color will not printed. only note section is printed.